# Counting elements meeting a predicate in an enumerable without iterating the entire sequence

Tags: c#, .net, iterator, lazy

I was reading [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/193487/finding-count-of-character-occurrences-in-a-string), and the [answer that mentioned streams](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/193496/73844), and a thought had occurred to me.

In many cases (at least in my usage) I want to determine if a sequence (or `IEnumerable`) has at least a certain number of elements, or has no more than a certain number, etc, that all match a predicate.

As it stands now, we have the `IEnumerable<T>.Count(Func<T, bool>)` method, but it will enumerate the entire `IEnumerable<T>` before returning. In some cases, we know we only care if there are certain numbers of values. (Such as exactly 8.)

As a result, I've built out a set of *new* extension methods to `IEnumerable<T>`, that add some functionality for counting *only as needed*. That is, if we care that we only have *at least `n`*, we can now deal with that in particular.

```
public static class IEnumerableTCountExtensions
{
    public static bool CountAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count == required) { break; }
            }
        }
        return count == required;
    }
    public static bool CountAbove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count > required) { break; }
            }
        }
        return count > required;
    }
    public static bool CountEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count > required) { return false; }
            }
        }
        return count == required;
    }
    public static bool CountNotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count > required) { return true; }
            }
        }
        return count != required;
    }
    public static bool CountBelow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count >= required) { return false; }
            }
        }
        return count < required;
    }
    public static bool CountNoMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                count++;
                if (count == required) { return false; }
            }
        }
        return count <= required;
    }
}
```

There are 6 functions: one for each of the following:

- `>=`: `CountAtLeast`;
- `>`: `CountAbove`;
- `==`: `CountEqual`;
- `!=`: `CountNotEqual`;
- `<`: `CountBelow`;
- `<=`: `CountNoMoreThan`;

Each of them short-circuits as reasonable, to allow us to only enumerate *what we have to*. The short-circuit path is taken in the case that it's acceptable.

A quick set of tests, with a pass/fail for each, is:

```
var things = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }.AsEnumerable().Select(x => { Console.WriteLine(x); return x; });
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountAtLeast(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountAtLeast(x => x <= 5, 6));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountAbove(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountAbove(x => x <= 5, 5));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 5));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 6));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 5));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 6));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountBelow(x => x <= 5, 6));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountBelow(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountNoMoreThan(x => x <= 5, 6));
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountNoMoreThan(x => x <= 5, 2));
```

The `Console.WriteLine(x);` is included to demonstrate that each item is only being iterated *as maximally necessary*, and can be removed for easier visual.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are so many different solutions already that I won't post another. But there is something else that bothers me, the names of the extensions. I find they are too confusing. Expecially `Above` and `Below`. They are not very technical (at leat in this context).

I think they should be called the same way we call the conditions they are based on and that are (or should be) familiar to all developers. This means:

Two of them already folow that pattern:

```
CountEqual
CountNotEqual
```

The rest should be:

```
CountLessThan
CountLessThanOrEqual
CountGreaterThan
CountGreaterThanOrEqual
```

Comment: Totally agree, I screwed the pooch on that one. :)

Answer (score 15):

You can use the Linq [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx) to accomplish the same thing

```
public static class IEnumerableTCountExtensions
{
    public static bool CountAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required).Count();
        return count == required;
    }
    public static bool CountAbove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count();
        return count > required;
    }
    public static bool CountEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count();
        return count == required;
    }
    public static bool CountNotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count();
        return count != required;
    }
    public static bool CountBelow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required).Count();
        return count < required;
    }
    public static bool CountNoMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        var count = items.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count();
        return count <= required;
    }
}
```

The only different in enumeration is the CountNoMoreThan as the original code has a short circuit on `if (count == required) { return false; }` which wouldn't know if there are more just that we hit the target and return false so it would seem a less than clause and not a less than or equal to. I'm thinking this might be a bug in the original code since the return statement is doing a less than or equals.

Also should add the guard clauses like Jesse C. Slicer suggested.

Comment: [MoreLinq](https://morelinq.github.io/3.0/ref/api/html/Methods_T_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable.htm) is also available. It contains `AssertCount`, `AtLeast` and `AtMost`.

Comment: Doesn't an in-memory `IEnumerable` (i.e. not an `IQueryable`) iterate over the entire array directly when calling `Where()`? If so, that would defeat OP's purpose. Or does it still do the "IQueryable approach" (deferred execution) even if the collection is in-memory?

Comment: @Flater yes, execution is deferred.

Comment: Aye, this is how I would do it in F#, so it makes sense to do the same here. :)

Answer (score 8):

With the help of LINQ and some helper methods, you can achieve the same with a lot less repetitive code.

How do we do it? Well we extract the `foreach` loop into an iterator which will return the current count of predicate matches:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetMatchingValues<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(item))
        {
            yield return ++count;
        }
    }
}
```

Once you have that it's a lot easier to see the pattern, most of those functions are either `.Any` or `.All` invocations, except for 1 odd case which really annoys me, perhaps someone smarter can figure it out:

```
public static bool CountAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return GetMatchingValues(items, predicate).Any(count => count == required);
}

public static bool CountAbove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return GetMatchingValues(items, predicate).Any(count => count > required);
}

public static bool CountEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    int finalCount = 0;
    foreach (int count in GetMatchingValues(items, predicate))
    {
        finalCount = count;
        if (finalCount > required) { break; }
    }
    return finalCount == required;
}

public static bool CountNotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return !CountEqual(items, predicate, required);
}

public static bool CountBelow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return !GetMatchingValues(items, predicate).Any(count => count >= required);
}

public static bool CountNoMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return GetMatchingValues(items, predicate).All(count => count != required);
}
```

Comment: @Flater OP wants to break asap and prevent further searching if we check the whole collection it won't be the same as Ops solution. With iterator 12345 is the worst case, it might be 123 tho, which is not possible with normal foreach

Comment: @Flater the iterator does not know when the end is. That's why it returns all the values. If you believe there is a cleaner approach please post an answer or add a short snippet in Fiddle and drop it here. I will be very interested in it.

Comment: @Flater It is effectively omitting the local variable declaration and it allows us to operate on the predicate matches as a sequence of elements instead of separate integers. It's true that only the last is important but I don't see a way of doing it otherwise, that's why I asked you to add a snippet if you know a better way of doing it.

Comment: @Flater The iterator is not aware of the magic number.  It needs to return 1,2,3,4,5 because the iterator does not know the magic number is 5.  The magic number may have been 3.

Comment: @Flater The benefit is less repeated code compared to the OP.

Comment: @Flater So it can be achieved without IEnumerable.  That is not how this solution was designed.  You could have posted a solution 2 hours ago when he asked you to.

Comment: @Flater I'm not quite sure how you interpret *If you believe there is a cleaner approach please post an answer or add a short snippet in Fiddle and drop it here. I will be very interested in it.* or *It's true that only the last is important but I don't see a way of doing it otherwise*. If anything it's lack of interest to actually read my comments.

Comment: @Flater would you like to continue the discussion in a [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76956/counting-elements-meeting-a-predicate-in-an-enumerable-without-iterating-the-enti)? I feel there is some misunderstanding here.

Answer (score 6):

Two minor recommendations:

1. Rename `items` to `source` to be in-line with how [LINQ does it](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/893708a4c46047af6fb14bc0f2c33b3ca6adc527/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L49).
2. Add parameter checking to the beginning of the methods as [LINQ does](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/893708a4c46047af6fb14bc0f2c33b3ca6adc527/src/System.Linq/src/System/Linq/Count.cs#L51):

   ```
       if (source == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
       }

       if (predicate == null)
       {
           throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
       }
   ```

And it looks solid!

**ETA:** Given the other super-cool answers, adding in the magic of C#7, I've refactored a little bit:

```
public static class IEnumerableTCountExtensions
{
    public static bool CountGreaterThanOrEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required).Count() == required);

    public static bool CountGreaterThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count() > required);

    public static bool CountEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count() == required);

    public static bool CountNotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count() != required);

    public static bool CountLessThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required).Count() < required);

    public static bool CountLessThanOrEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required) => source == null
        ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source))
        : (predicate == null
            ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate))
            : source.Where(predicate).Take(required + 1).Count() <= required);
}
```

Comment: I know this is just a style preference but I never like using ternary conditional operator for throwing.  I prefer to either have the guard clause or have a static guard class that does the checking.  Or even better to use code contracts.

Answer (score 5):

The action which is taken if the `if` condition is true isn't consitent. Sometimes you `return` out of the `if` and sometimes you `break` out of the loop althougth you could do it the same way.

E.g

In `CountAbove` you break if `count > required` to `return count > required` but in `CountEqual` you `return false` if `count > required` and if that `if` condition is never evaluated to `true` you `return count == required`.

---

You could use some pre-check to make sure you won't need to iterate at all by soft-casting the `IEnumerable<T> items` to an `ICollection<T>`/`ICollection` and if the soft-cast succeed you can check the `Count` property.

You may say but what about the `predicate`? Well e.g. for `CountAbove` the `Count` property of the `ICollection<T>`/`ICollection` needs to be at least greater than `required` like so

```
public static bool CountAbove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
{
    ICollection<T> collectionOfT = items as ICollection<T>;
    if (collectionOfT != null && collectionOfT.Count <= required) { return false; }
    ICollection collection = items as ICollection;
    if (collection != null && collection.Count <= required) { return false; }

    var count = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            count++;
            if (count > required) { break; }
        }
    }
    return count > required;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a variation on Denis' answer. While his answer works, it is returning a progressive count (1,2,3,4,5) for no good reason. In the end, you're only interested in the last number (5) that is returned, so there is no point to wrapping the count in an `IEnumerable`.

Furthermore, because of the combined use of logical inversions, `Any` and `All`, Denis' code (**while it does work**) becomes quite hard to quickly read through. There is a difference between e.g. `!myList.All(x => x == myValue)` and `myList.All(x => x != myValue)`, but the distinction is hard to miss here.

Comparatively, the distinction between `myCount == myValue` and `myCount != myValue` is much easier to parse at a glance, which is why I think my answer is better from a readability standpoint (even though it is functionally equivalent, which I do concede).

---

### The counting algorithm

```
private static int CountMatchesUpTo<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int boundary)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        if (predicate.Invoke(item))
        {
            count++;
        }

        if(count == boundary)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return count;
}
```

There are two possible ways that the `return` statement can be reached:

- Because the `foreach` completed. This happens if you have less than `boundary` matches in your list, since you keep looking for matches **up to** the boundary.
- Because the `boundary` was reached. At this point, the `foreach` is forcefully broken out of, and the count (equal to boundary) is returned. The remaining items of the list were never iterated over.

---

### The wrapper methods

The implementation of most of the other methods is relatively easy to do.

Notice that in some cases, I use `required + 1` as the upper bound. This is relevant in cases where you want to distinguish between a match count that is either equal to or greater than the boundary.

Assuming you're using a boundary of 5, you then instruct the counting method to look for **6** items.

- If it returns 6, then you know that there are **more than 5 matches**.
- If it returns 5, then you know that there are **exactly 5 matches** (the same applies for a smaller return value).

This takes care of the "upper" short circuit. The "lower" short circuit is already taken care of as you will receive a lower number if not enough matches were found.

```
public static bool CountEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required + 1) == required;
}

public static bool CountNotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required + 1) != required;
}

public static bool CountAbove<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required + 1) > required;
}

public static bool CountAtLeast<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required) == required;
}
```

---

```
public static bool CountBelow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
{
    var count = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            count++;
            if (count >= required) { return false; }
        }
    }
    return count < required;
}

public static bool CountNoMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
{
    var count = 0;
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            count++;
            if (count == required) { return false; }
        }
    }
    return count <= required;
}
```

There are two things to notice here:

**1** - In one method, you do `if (count >= required) { return false; }`, and in the other, you do `if (count == required) { return false; }`. Since `count` is incrementing one at a time, `count >= required` will evaluate to true because it `count` is **equal** to `required`. `Count` will never be greater than `required` since you exit the method when it already equals it.

**2** - `CountNoMoreThan` is also unintuitive for another reason: you do `if (count == required) { return false; }` and then `return count <= required;`.
The return statement will **never** find a case where `count` equals `required`, since you've already explicitly returned false when you find an equality. The return statement can therefore be refactored to `return count < required;`.

Combining the findings of **1** and **2**, this means that `CountBelow` and `CountNoMoreThan` are currently **functionally equivalent methods**. There's no point to having both methods.

From the method names, I surmise that the difference between the two is `<` or `<=`. Using my refactored approach, the difference is easy to implement:

```
public static bool CountNoMoreThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required + 1) <= required;
}
```

Note that we again use `required+1`, to allow for the count method to tell us if there are more matches than the boundary.

```
public static bool CountBelow<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Predicate<T> predicate, int required)
{
    return CountMatchesUpTo(items, predicate, required) < required;
}
```

---

### Footnote

As it stands, all the listed methods are merely an enumeration of int comparisons: `==`, `!=`, `>`, `>=`, `<`, `<=`.

There is little point to doing this. You can simply make `CountMatchesUpTo` a publically accessible method, and rely on your caller to do their own evaluation.

If you're already expecting your caller to know which method to use, that means that they know which evaluation they want to take place. There is no added benefit from putting it in an additional method layer.

If you're doing more cumbersome logic (e.g. checking if two datetimes overlap), that is relevant to put into a method, as it would be cumbersome to write every time. But your current evaluations are not complex enough to warrant their own method layer.

The issue here is that your additional layer is an additional place for bugs to sneak into the code. And it already did, as I found a bug in `CountNoMoreThan`. If uncaught, external consumers of your methods would be hunting for bugs in their own code, unaware that your method is simply not doing what its name advertises.

---

### Update

***Update is not correct. See below.***

Two of your tests appear to be incorrect:

```
Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));
Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));
```

Since you set the boundary at `2`, the "count up to" algorithm will logically stop iterating over the collection once it reaches a count of **2**.

This means that `things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 2)` will return **true**, and `things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 2)` will return false.

Your test seemingly expects that the counting method will still count 5 elements; which violates the algorithm (as it should stop after the defined boundary, which in this case is 2).

It's an easy mistake to make; one that I had initially glossed over too, as I understood what you were trying to test. But the expected outcome of these two tests should be inverted; otherwise it would violate your proposed algorithm.

**Update to the update**

The requirements were clarified by OP in chat. The above code has been altered to reflect that.

Comment: As far as I like your comments (+1) I always find this argument very weak: _The issue here is that your additional layer is an additional place for bugs to sneak into the code._ - I treat creating convenience extensions (or any other resusable code) always a good thing because I'm a lazy engineer ;-) sure, there might be some bugs (usually at the beginning) but you know where to find them and they are easier to test and to fix and what's even more imporatnt, you're doing this only once and when you're done, you never have to implement this logic again so it's actually a good thing.

Comment: @t3chb0t: I'm all for convenience extensions (as I mentioned for datetime overlap). However, the current methods are wrapping the most elementary of comparison operators. There is a reasonability argument here; if the method doesn't shorten the code and choosing the correct method requires the same level of knowledge as doing the comparison yourself; there's no convenience from having the method. Comparatively, Datetime overlap comparison is a reasonable convenience, because it's cumbersome to always write the _multiple_ comparison evaluations needed to correctly check for an overlap.

Comment: For us outsiders/readers, it's always difficult to tell whether something is useful/convenient or not as we might not have the need for it yet but I guess OP might have already be using similar code multiple times so in his projects this is a convenience. Another such example could be [my extensions for testing common interfaces](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/175754/asserting-that-popular-interfacs-are-correctly-implemented). Not much feedback received, probalby because nobody is doing this but I'm using them in many projects; it's relative :-]

Comment: `CountEqual` and `CountNotEqual` don't quite work, at least the way it's posted here, you should run the tests OP has provided.

Comment: @Flater those 2 tests specifically `Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));`, `Console.WriteLine("T? " + things.CountNotEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));`.

Comment: @Flater I'm sorry I posted the same test twice the first one should be: `Console.WriteLine("F? " + things.CountEqual(x => x <= 5, 2));`. The first one returns `true` when the expected output should be `false` and the second returns `false` when the expected output is `true`. The `NotEqual 6` works fine just like all the rest of the tests except the ones I mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76958/discussion-between-denis-and-flater).

Answer (score 4):

A method that returns a count and stop at a target count can do all that logic.
I like more mathematical names.

```
public static class IEnumerableTCountExtensions
{
    private static int CountMatchingStopAt<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int stopAt)
    {
        int count = 0;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (predicate.Invoke(item))
            {
                count++;
                if(count == stopAt)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static bool GreaterThanOrEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required + 1) >= required;
    }
    public static bool GreaterThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required + 1) == required + 1;
    }
    public static bool Equal<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required + 1) == required;
    }
    public static bool NotEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required + 1) != required;
    }
    public static bool LessThan<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required) < required;
    }
    public static bool LessThanOrEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> predicate, int required)
    {
        return CountMatchingStopAt(items, predicate, required + 1) <= required;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Each of them short-circuits as reasonable, to allow us to only enumerate *what we have to*. The short-circuit path is taken in the case that it's acceptable.

Not quite. There are some missing corner cases when `required <= 0` (or `required < 0` for the exact test).